# The relativity of simultaneity in two-photon absorption

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-optics, spectroscopy, non-linear-optics

In the two-photon absorption (TPA) process, when there is no intermediate state, it's required that two photons are absorbed either **simultaneously or semi-simultaneously**, with a relatively short time delay between consecutive absorptions, as observed in experiments. My question is: Is the concept of simultaneous absorption relative to the lab observer or the atom's center of mass (CM)? In the semi-simultaneous case, is the time delay measured in the lab frame or in the atom’s CM frame? Could the perceived time delay be resulted from some sort of time dilation in the atom's CM frame? Additionally, can we identify a reference frame where the two photons are absorbed consecutively but with a **significant** delay, yet still leading to two-photon absorption and exploring TPA-allowed excited states? If such a frame exists, how does it perceive the electronic energy diagram of the atom? I speculate that this specific observer would observe new intermediate energy levels, facilitating the scenario where photons can be absorbed non-simultaneously during the TPA process.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the concept of simultaneous absorption relative to the lab observer or the atom's center of mass (CM)?

Either way, it doesn't matter. All reference frames agree when things happen at the same time and same place. In spacetime terms this is an "event" a time and a place. It doesn't matter how many things physically happen at that event, they are all the same event. So here, the two photons being simultaneously absorbed by a single atom is all a single event. So, the absorptions will be simultaneous in all reference frames.

From your comment

> the absorption of the two photons is so infinitesimally small that it falls within the bounds of Heisenberg uncertainty, rendering it perceived as simultaneous

This is not “perceived as simultaneous”. This “is simultaneous”. Within that time there is not a sense in which one photon has definitely been absorbed and the other has definitely not been absorbed. What you have is a wavefunction that is evolving and which is in a state that doesn’t have a definite number of photons.

Comment: I have not heard that it could be semi-simultaneously. I don't even know what "semi simultaneously" is supposed to mean. Do you have a source for this concept?

Comment: Semi-simultaneous means the atom absorbs the first photon and then after a very short period absorbs the other photon. My another question is that this short time delay is measured in the atom’s CM frame or in the lab frame?

Comment: Btw, my first comment was accidentally removed by myself. Thanks for your comment on the simultaneous case! I think you're right that a simultaneous TPA is a single event, and every inertial observer must see it happen similarly.

Comment: @Omid There is always an intermediate state in TPA ..... you are trying to imply that EM wave amplitude is the only consideration. It is the frequency of  electron/photon resonance that is key to excitation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, there isn't always a real intermediate level; some argue for the existence of virtual intermediate states for convenience. However, in some molecular examples, there are indeed real intermediate states, but again not in all media.

Comment: @Omid, well, I definitely can imagine that the discussion about the existence of the levels as a formalism exists. However I do think they are real intermediate steps: take a system where third harmonic is being driven by a strong source, now add a weak secondary source with a different photon energy and you will immediately find the four-wave mixing signal, which appears only through the interaction with the second virtual level of the 3-step THG signal. One could argue that its still all (non-existent) virtual, but in a way they are definitely real when solving Maxwell eqs.